# Does anyone know an good free natural sounding text reader for the mac?

Tags: macos

Does anyone know an good free natural sounding text reader for the mac?

Answer (score 6):

Does it not have one built in? I suspect it's as natural sounding as you'd get for free.

Answer (score 4):

OS X has built-in speech services for any Cocoa app.  Just select the text and click AppName->Services->Speech->Start Speaking Text

Additionally, Preview can read PDFs quite nicely.  Just open the PDF and select Edit->Speech->Start Speaking.

The default Alex voice (in Leopard at least) is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the voices on the Speech application (in System Preferences?)

Comment: No. I think you don't understand the difference between "Natural Voices" and "Microsoft-like Voices". It's huge.

Comment: About as much as the difference between 'free' and 'paying some money'

Answer (score 1):

A couple of the built-in voices sound much better than the others. In particular, one of the new voices, "Alex", I believe, sounds much more natural than the others.